# How to check that ES6 "variable" is constant?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Does anyone know some tricks how to do it? I tried to use `try-catch`:

```
"use strict";

const a = 20;

var isConst = false;
try {
   var temp = a; a = a+1; a = temp;
} catch (e) {
   isConst = true;
}
```

But unfortunately it works only in "strict" mode. Without "use strict" it perform all statements silently, without modification of `a`. Also I cannot wrap this code into some handy function (`isConstant(someConst)` for example) as any argument I'll pass to that function will be a new variable. So anyone know how to create `isConstant()` function?

Comment: For me `const a=2;a++;` throws a `SyntaxError` (“invalid assignment to const a”), using Firefox 37.0, even without strict mode and I don’t have `javascript.options.strict` enabled. Another one is a `TypeError`: “redeclaration of const a” if I do `const a=2;delete a;` or `const a=2;const a=2;`.

Comment: Interesting question. I don't think it's possible to determine for most browsers- at least [according to Mozilla's compatibility chart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const#Browser_compatibility)- but I'd be very curious if there is a way to detect it.

Comment: What browser do you use? Because as far as Firefox 37.0 is concerned a `try-catch` that tries to redefine a constant and catches syntax errors could work.

Comment: @Xufox Chrome Canary.

Comment: What's the reason for this?

Comment: @FelixKling There is no reason:) I'm just playing around with ES6 features.

Comment: @alexpods I use VS Code with the ESLint plugin. It helps identify variables and their declarations. If you `let x = 1` and never change the value of `x`, it prompts you to convert it ti `const x = 1` and so on.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is, but I also don't think this is a big issue. I think it might be useful to have the ability to know if a variable is `const`, and this exists in some other languages, but in reality since you (or someone on a team) will be defining these variables, you'd know the scope and the type of the variables. In other words, no you can't, but it's also not an issue.

The only case where it might be useful is if you could change the `mutable` property during runtime, and if changing this property had actual performance benefits; `let`, `const`, and `var` are treated roughly equally to the compiler, the only difference is that the compiler keeps track of `const` and will check assignments before it even compiles.

Another thing to note is that just like `let`, `const` is scoped to the current scope, so if you have something like this:

```
'use strict';

const a = 12;

// another scope
{
  const a = 13;
}
```

it's valid. Just be careful that it will look up in higher scopes if you don't explicitly state `const a = 13` in that new scope, and it will give a `Read Only` or `Assignment` error:

```
'use strict';

const a = 12;

{
  a = 13; // will result in error
}
```

Comment: Good answer. But unfortunately v8 does not raise an error if you're running your script in "non-strict" mode. Nevetherless - thanks.

Comment: Generally linters like `jshint` will complain if you don't have `use strict;` in your code, so I consider that somewhat of a moot point. It's pretty rare to see code that *doesn't* include `use strict;` in any kind of production setting.

Comment: Well, I agree with you. Upvote from me. But actually the question is more academical, not a real issue. I've just occasionly came to this question how to correctly check that "variable" is a constant. I don't know even the real use case where it can be useful:)

Answer (score 2):

Based on some of the answers here I wrote this code snippet (for client side JS) that will tell you how a "variable" was last declared--I hope it's useful.

Use the following to find out what `x` was last declared as (uncomment the declarations of `x` to test it):

```js
// x = 0
// var x = 0
// let x = 0
// const x = 0

const varName = "x"    
console.log(`Declaration of ${varName} was...`)
try {
  eval(`${varName}`)
  try {
    eval(`var ${varName}`);
    console.log("... last made with var")
  } catch (error) {
    try {
      eval(`${varName} = ${varName}`)
      console.log("... last made with let")
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("... last made with const")
    }
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.log("... not found. Undeclared.")
}
```

Interestingly, declaring without `var`, `let` or `const`, i.e `x = 0`, results in `var` getting used by default. Also, function arguments are re-declared in the function scope using `var`.

Comment: You could use `eval(\`${varName} = ${varName}\`);` to preserve the value of the variable, while still checking whether assignment is allowed

Comment: @MatthewJensen much better, thank you! (Have corrected the code above.)

Answer (score 0):

**The question refers to incompliant behaviour in earlier ES6 implementations, notably V8 (Node.js 4 and legacy Chrome versions). The problem doesn't exist in modern ES6 implementations, both in strict and sloppy modes. `const` reassignment should always result in `TypeError`, it can be caught with `try..catch`.**

There can't be `isConstant` function because `const` variable cannot be identified as such by its value.

It's preferable to run a script in strict mode and thus avoid problems that are specific to sloppy mode.

Even if a variable was defined in sloppy mode, it's possible to enable strict mode in nested function scope:

```
const foo = 1;
// ...
let isConst = false;

(() => {
  'use strict';

  try {
    const oldValue = foo;
    foo = 'new value';
    foo = oldValue;
  } catch (err) {
     isConst = true;
  }
})();
```

It's beneficial to use `UPPERCASE_CONSTANT` convention which is used in JavaScript and other languages. It allows to unambiguously identify a variable as a constant without aid from IDE and avoid most problems with accidental reassignments.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if your reassignment actually did something:

```
var isConst = function(name, context) {
  // does this thing even exist in context?
  context = context || this;
  if(typeof context[name] === "undefined") return false;
  // if it does exist, a reassignment should fail, either
  // because of a throw, or because reassignment does nothing.
  try {
    var _a = context[name];
    context[name] = !context[name];
    if (context[name] === _a) return true;
    // make sure to restore after testing!
    context[name] = _a;
  } catch(e) { return true; }
  return false;
}.bind(this);
```

You need the try/catch because reassign *Could* throw an exception (like in Firefox), but when it doesn't (like in Chrome), you just check whether your "this always changes the value" reassignment actually *did* anything.

A simple test:

```
const a = 4;
var b = "lol";
isConst('a'); // -> true
isConst('b'); // -> false
```

And if you declare the consts in different context, pass that context in to force resolution on the correct object.

downside: this won't work on vars declared outside of object scopes. upside: it makes absolutely no sense to declare them anywhere else. For instance, declaring them in function scope makes the `const` keyword mostly useless:

```
function add(a) {
  return ++a;
}

function test() {
  const a = 4;
  console.log(add(a));
}

test(); // -> 5
```

Even though `a` is constant inside test(), if you pass it to anything else, it's passed as a regular mutable value because it's now just "a thing" in the `arguments` list.

In addition, the only reason to have a `const` is because it does not change. As such, constantly recreating it because you're calling a function that makes use of it more than once, means your `const` should live outside the function instead, so again, we're forced to put the variable in an object scope.

Comment: notice the `context` variable, where you can pass in your own context where you expect the variable to live.

Comment: Well, It doesn't work if you run it in first time: `(function() { const e = 30; console.log(isConst('e')); })()` In the second time it works.

Comment: good point, let me see if I can update the answer to cover you there.

Comment: `context[name] = !a;` you're poulting the context here (most likely global context)

Comment: yeah sorry, that's a typo. I'm not polluting, btw, I'm incorrectly rewriting. The context[name] already existed, because that's what we're looking for. updated the code for that.

Comment: `(function() { const e = 30; var f = 40; console.log(isConst('e'), isConst('f')); })();` still doesn't work (false, false);

Comment: @JoshuaSmock How to get context of self invoking anonymous function?

Comment: using `const` in a function is using `const` wrong. Either declare it *outside* of a function, because it's a constant value, and you're going to call that function many times, so you have *no reason* to redeclare it time and again, or you're using it as a convenient "I can't change this value during the function run", in which case you don't need a const. You need to write you code properly so that value is only ever a RHS value, never LHS.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans in ES6 you have modules. How you get reference to the module context?

Comment: That depends entirely on the code you're writing, much like is the case for AMD or CommonJS module code right now.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I also don't think that that "using `const` in functions is wrong". Currently in my ES6 code I declare almost all my variable using `const` and very little as `let`, and it works pretty well. I don't see any problem with it, only benefits.

Comment: correction: you're declaring your *constants* as `const`. If you need constants, then redeclaring them every time the function is called will work just fine, and also completely misses the point of using constants. They're invariant, they only need defining once, so if you find your code redeclaring them *even once* that's the sign you have them being declared them at the wrong scoping depth.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans it's good programming practice (to declare constants in the highest scope) but it doesn't matter here because the JIT doesn't care if it's `const` or `let` - they're treated basically the same and declaring `const` may actually have perf benefits.

Comment: they're really not. `consts` come with additional baggage to ensure single assignments, where `let` does not. As for perf: if you are considering "may have", verify that hypothesis. I'm fairly certain that much like as in the last few years (when `const` was already supported), `var` and `let` are still faster. But more importantly I think you will agree that if we're talking performance, *not redeclaring* is even faster than repeatedly allocating and then GCing a `const`, for obvious reasons.